# Rigid $Hom$-orthogonal modules in wild hereditary algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, associative-algebras

Let $Q$ be a simply-laced wild quiver with at least one multiple edge, $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $1$ be the source of and $2$ be the sink of one set of such edges. Can we find rigid indecomposable modules $L, M, N\in mod kQ$ such that $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$, $\{1,2\}\subseteq supp M$, $Ext^1(L,N) =0, Ext^1(N,L) = k$ and one of the followings is true:

1. $1\in supp L, 2\in supp N, 1 \notin supp N, 2\notin supp L$.
2. $2\in supp L, 1\in supp N, 2 \notin supp N, 1\notin supp L$.